# tomcat is not autodeploying my .war file

Tags: java, tomcat

i hope this is no duplicate. I allready searched for an answer, but did not find anything that fits.

I have a .war file called "app.war" and put it into the webapps folder of my tomcat. When i start tomcat, the .war file should actually be deployed, but it does not.

In my server.xml unpackWARs and autoDeploy is set to true. The tomcat service in the system is installed.

Does the content of the war file needs to have a special structure? I have the following structure:

[image: app.war structure]

I create the .war file with gradle by using "gradle build". My project structure is a typical maven java webapp structure.

Is there maybe anything missing in the war file? I have no more idea why the war file is not being deployed. What is also strange to me, is that when i unzip the war file in the webapps folder and restart my tomcat, the app won't be found by the tomcat.

Comment: More info is needed. e.g. COMPLETE structure of your project, how did you build the war, how did you verify that the war is not deployed, etc..

Comment: Can you also post the catalina.out when deploying your war ?

Comment: Did you check is there any error in localhost/catalina

Comment: i cannot find the localhost/catalina folder... is that maybe the problem? i actually just downloaded a fresh tomcat, so i wonder why the folder is not there

Comment: There is no folder as such. These are the logs file under <tomcat_home>/logs

Comment: there are no logs at all...the server is just really leaving out the app.war

Comment: for those who are maybe interested: i found the solution on my own...i allready had a tomcat service with an own catalina_home installed and everytime when i started catalina.bat, it was just scanning the catalina_home but not the actual directory where i putted my war file into

Comment: Your `web.xml` is supposed to be in `WEB-INF/web.xml`, unless that's an unrelated file from your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the permission of the war file and the webapps folder?  Commonly tomcat is started by a user different to root , so , If you copied the file as root, the tomcat process never can access it .